# How to connect C# to Snowflake Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect to the Snowflake database using ADO.Net. It seems it's not supported. There are many 3rd parties connector. I want to know which one is good,  and how to use it. E.g. how can I insert data into a Snowflake table.

Comment: Was this solved? Spoke with Snowflake tech support, sounds like snowflake is built by a group of Mac users who don't care much about .NET/C#.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following NuGet package Snowflake.Data
For more information please see visit this   https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net

```
using (IDbConnection conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        conn.Open();

        IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into t values (?),(?),(?)";
        IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        var p1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
        p1.ParameterName = "1";
        p1.Value = 10;
        p1.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

        var p2 = cmd.CreateParameter();
        p2.ParameterName = "2";
        p2.Value = 10000L;
        p2.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);

        var p3 = cmd.CreateParameter();
        p3.ParameterName = "3";
        p3.Value = (short)1;
        p3.DbType = DbType.Int16;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);

        var count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Assert.AreEqual(3, count);             

        conn.Close();
    }
```